# Replace the broken file copying UI in Windows 2008 Server 64-bit Explorer

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, printer

Does anyone know a good GUI alternative for file copying on a Windows 2008 Server 64 bit edition. The built-in GUI has a hopeless interface and is bug-riddled which really hinders the ability to get things done safely. For example, often when moving a directory with subfolders, the directory and its subfolders will still remain, empty and not deleted.

I've been through many of the common file copier and Windows Explorer alternatives, but either they flat-out do not work on a 64 bit/W2k8 machine or they do not actually fully replace the file copier.

Answer (score 1):

If you open a directory and move all the files and folders from that directory, that directory will remain.  That is by design.

For truly improved performance of moving data around, don't use the GUI at all.  Use robocopy (which is included with Windows 2008) to copy/move data around the system.  It's very powerful, and quick.  Much quicker than the GUI will ever be.

The ability to copy/move files and folders can't be that bug riddled as millions of people use it without issue daily.

Comment: All of the subfolders also remain. That's the bug.

Comment: Having just copied and then moved about 10000 (nope that's not a typo) folders chock full o' files (upwards of 100,000) using explorer just to see if there was an issue- it can't be that bug riddled as it worked without a hitch though slower than the command line.  This was on server 2k8 DC edition to DC edition over 1gb lan

Comment: Are you sure the copy isn't failing?  I've never seen files get left when doing a move.  A copy yes, but that's to be expected.

Comment: Files don't remain. Subfolders remain.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advocate using FAR manager as a replacement for windows explorer. Things are far easier to accomplish without touching a mouse, and the learning curve really is not that bad. Also, works absolutely fine on 2k8 x64, even on server core installations.

Comment: thumbs up for far. open source / free since a while ; http://farmanager.com/download.php?l=en

Answer (score 0):

I share your dislike of Explorer, but I have forced myself to get used to it because when I go to some random server it's the only file manager that is guaranteed to be there. Given that I usually get called upon to dial into servers when there's a problem they want me to fix, I rarely have time to mess around installing my favourite file manager.

But on my own workstation (W2k8 x64) I use the good old Windows File Manager, as shipped with Windows since Windows NT 3.1. For the simple day to day file management tasks I have yet to find anything faster or more reliable. I have tried many third party file managers and they all seem to be too cluttered and/or too slow.

JR